# Can somebody give me an example of using jsf converters?

Tags: java, jsf, converters

I want to convert the text entered by someone into a textbox into a double(for example), and automatically set up the value of an bean field with that double.

Answer (score 1):

- implement `javax.faces.convert.Converter`
- in the `getAsString(..)` method use `object.toString()`
- in the `getAsObject(..)` method use `new BigDecimal(str)` / `Double.parseDouble(str)` / `Integer.parseInt(str)`. Use `instanceof` to differentiate between the types.
- register the converter in faces-config.xml.

Comment: the answer is a little bit to vague for my level of java. I'd be thankful if you coud be a little bit more explicit. Practically I have a bean with 2 strings which should be numbers(BigDecimal, double, int). How can I do this with a converter?

Comment: @Csaryus - I can write it instead of you, but make some effort. My explanation should be sufficient to implement the class you need.

Comment: It's true, but I was having a time constraint.